# Nginx: how to set up multiple servers with accept_filter=httpready

Tags: nginx, freebsd

On a FreeBSD machine, I have a super-simple Nginx conf file (nginx/1.8.1):

```
server {
  server_name .domain1.com;
  listen 80 accept_filter=httpready;
  index index.html;
  location / {
      root /home/www1;
  }
}

server {
  server_name domain2.com;
  listen 80 default_server accept_filter=httpready;
  index index.htm;
  location / {
      root /home/www2;
  }
}
```

This works if I only have `accept_filter=httpready` enabled for one of the servers. But as it is written above, it fails, with

nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for 0.0.0.0:80

Why can't I set `accept_filter=httpready` for both servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nginx.org/r/listen

> The `listen` directive can have several additional parameters specific to socket-related system calls. These parameters can be specified in any `listen` directive, but **only once** for a given **`address:port`** pair.

So you should use `accept_filter=httpready` only once, but it will be effective for all server blocks that listen to the same `address:port`.